# Twitter Search API IDs meaning

Tags: twitter

I am using the [Twitter Search API](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/using-search) and I can't understand the `id` field of a tweet.

For example here is one: `<id>tag:search.twitter.com,2005:1990561514</id>`. The real ID is the final number part, right? Why doesn't Twitter already provide this in a single element? And, why is there a year of `2005`on the ID field? Is that the ID of that year and the following year tweets get an ID recounted to zero? Is the ID indexed to the year?

I am asking all this stuff, because I am going to use the option of `since_id` to retrive new tweets. If the ID isn't really unique and depends on the year, it won't work as expected.

Thanks.

Comment: Please post the code of your query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tag is unique - but parts of it are redundant.

```
tag:search.twitter.com,2005:1990561514
```

Obviously, search.twitter.com is the URL from where you requested the document.

The ,2005 is constant.  As far as I can tell, it has never changed since the service was launched.  While there's no official documentation, I would guess that it refers to the ATOM specification namespace - http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"

Finally, the long number is the Tweet's status ID.  It will always be unique and can be used for the since_id.

What you will need to do is split the string, and just use the number after the colon as your ID.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Would you like to add to your answer where did you get that info? Thanks.

Comment: I just looked at the source of the ATOM feed. You can see that the long number is the unique ID by plugging it back into Twitter e.g. https://twitter.com/x/status/1990561514

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are doing something wrong. If you look at all of the example results from the Twitter Search API, none of the id fields are formatted like this one you are showing.

For example:

[http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=%40twitterapi%20-via](http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=@twitterapi%20-via)

Also, if you check out the [example requests page](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/search), you will see that all of the id fields have normal formats, i.e.:

```
"id":122032448266698752
```

Update:

Now that I know you are using the atom feed, I can see where the seemingly oddly formatted  element comes from. See [this article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-tipatom1/) on avoiding duplicates in atom feeds. [Another helpful article](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/cicsts/v4r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.cics.ts.internet.doc/topics/dfhtl_atom_atomids.html).

Basically, atom feeds REQUIRE a unique id for each element in a feed. Some feeds use the "tag" scheme to ensure uniqueness. This format is actually pretty common in atom feeds and many frameworks use it by default. For instance, the RoR [AtomFeedHelper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AtomFeedHelper.html) (which might even be what Twitter uses) specifies the default  format to be:

```
"tag:#{request.host},#{options}:#{request.fullpath.split(".")}"
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, however, I am using the **atom** format for the Twitter Search API, `http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=`, not **json**.